# Livewire x-slot tag in component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I search to use x-slot in Livewire component to populate my sidebar with wire:model form inputs.

My edit.blade.php file:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Header') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>

    <div>{{ $sidebar }}</div>

    <div class="bg-white">
        <livewire:editor-component :post="$post" />
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

My Livewire component:

```
<div>
    <x-slot name="sidebar">
        <div class="bg-gray-100">
            Some text... Some inputs...
        </div>
    </x-slot>

    <div class="p-5">
        <livewire:other-component />
    </div>
</div>
```

And my component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Post;
use Livewire\Component;

class EditorComponent extends Component
{
    /** @var Post */
    public $post;
}
```

I want access to $post in sidebar x-slot and I should be able to write in input and manage values of component from sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `$post` inside your Livewire view directly as it is a public property.

As example you can output the id of your `$post`, given that there is an `id` property on your `$post`, like this:

```html
<div>
    <x-slot name="sidebar">
        <div class="bg-gray-100">
            Some text... Some inputs...
        </div>
    </x-slot>

    Post id: {{ $post->id }}

    <div class="p-5">
        <livewire:other-component />
    </div>
</div>
```

How to access properties is written down in the [Livewire docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/properties)

**Access properties across components**, can be done by utilizing [Livewire Events](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events)